# HtmlAgilityPack close form tag automatically

Tags: .net, html, html-agility-pack

I am tring to parse an html file with this code:

```
<div><form>...</div>...</form>
```

the problem is that the HtmlAgilityPack automatically close the form tag before the div ending tag:
 `<div><form>...</form></div>...</form>`  so when I parse the form some of the form elements are missing. (I get only the elements befor the automatically added  tag)

I already tried:

```
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = false;
htmlDoc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = false;
htmlDoc.OptionCheckSyntax = false;
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("form", HtmlElementFlag.CanOverlap);
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("div", HtmlElementFlag.CanOverlap);
```

But nothing helps!

thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work for me:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");

_document = new HtmlDocument();
_document.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
_document.LoadHtml(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do *programmatically* after the text has been parsed. If you don't want to do anything special with it, the following code:

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml("<div><form>form and div</div>form</form>");

    doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

will display exactly the same string, that is:

```
<div><form>form and div</div>form</form>
```

Because the library was designed from the grounds up to try to keep the original Html as much as possible.

But in terms on how this is represented in the DOM, and in terms of errors, this is another story. You can't have at the same time 1) overlapping elements 2) XML-like DOM (which does not support overlaps) and 3) no errors.

So it depends on what you want to do after parsing.

Comment: I need to loop over the form children tags. So the problem is that I don’t get all the child tags, just the childes until the automatically added </form> tag.

Comment: @ido - hmmm... like I say, you can' have overlapping tags and DOM (parent/child relation) at the same time.

Comment: well I am parsing a site that does... and need a solution

Comment: Same boat.  HAP is doing weird things.. I'll pass it a chunk of markup to modify and it will make changes to it I did not request.  Not what I would have expected.

Comment: @jon - if you have a specific problem, please post a new question.