# Using HtmlAgilityPack to close tags at the end of a parent tag

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have the string `"<p><s>this is a test</p>"`.

Adding the code `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["s"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;` I'm able to auto-close the `s` tag, but it closes it straight after the opening tag. Is there any way I can get it to close it just before the closing `p` tag?

In the general case, how can I get HtmlAgilityPack to auto-close a tag just before the the parent tag is closed?

Comment: i am not sure refer this link you may got any solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104652/htmlagilitypack-close-form-tag-automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the parent tag with HTMLAgilityPack, get its text, get the length of the closing parent tag, add the closing child tag before the closing parent, replace tag

Comment: Was hoping for a more built-in method, but this will do for my purposes.

Comment: You can always create an extension which will look almost built-in. Anyways, I am glad it will suffice.